# Grease pencil, how do I use the shear tool?

Tags: grease-pencil

- In edit mode, I select all points, they turn amber.
- View shows: Front Orthographic
- I select the shear tool.
- I click, and there's an up down arrow cursor.
- I move it, nothing happens.
- I hit y key and now the cursor is left and right.
- I move the mouse while holding left key.
- My drawing is scaling in the X direction.

How do I shear my drawing?

Comment: I think my current version of 2.8 is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Until Blender get an official release 2.8 cannot be dependably consistent and might change its behavior from test version to test version. Trying a new version may change all the previous methods of using it.